# smallest match in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, greedy

I have this kind of expression:

```
var string = [a][1] [b][2] [c][3] [d .-][] [e][4]
```

I woud like to match the fourth element `[d .-][]` which may contain any character (letters, numbers, punctuation, etc) within the first pair of bracket but the second pair of bracket remains empty. Other elements, for example, `[a][1]`, may contain any character but they do have a number inside the second pair of brackets.

I tried this:

```
string.match(/\\[[^]+]\\[ ]/);
```

but it is too greedy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I woud like to match the fourth element [d .-][] which may contain any character (letters, numbers, punctuation, etc) within the first pair of bracket but the second pair of bracket remains empty

```
string.match(/\[[^\]]*\]\[\]/)
```

should do it.

To break it down,

`\[` matches a literal left square bracket,

`[^\]]*` matches any number of characters other than a right square bracket,

`\]` matches a literal right square bracket, and

`\[\]` matches the two character sequence `[]`, square brackets with nothing in between.

To answer your question about greediness though, you can make the greedy match `[^]+` non-greedy by adding a question-mark: `[^]+?`.  You should know though that `[^]` does not work in IE.  To match any UTF-16 code-unit I tend to use `[\s\S]` which is a bit more verbose but works on all browsers.

Comment: Thanks. It works great!. By the way, nice tip about using [^]+.